# How do I deep copy a DateTime object?

Tags: php, datetime

```
$date1 = $date2 = new DateTime();
$date2->add(new DateInterval('P3Y'));
```

Now `$date1` and `$date2` contain the same date -- three years from now. I'd like to create two separate datetimes, one which is parsed from a string and one with three years added to it. Currently I've hacked it up like this:

```
$date2 =  new DateTime($date1->format(DateTime::ISO8601));
```

but that seems like a horrendous hack. Is there a "correct" way to deep copy a DateTime object?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = new DateTime();
$date2->add(new DateInterval('P3Y'));
```

**Update:**

If you want to copy rather than reference an existing DT object, use `clone`, not `=`.

`$a = clone $b;`

Comment: I used a new DateTime in the example to demonstrate the point, but for now assume DateTime is returned from some opaque API that I can't just call over again. For example, I have a function that handles orders that returns a DateTime which is when the customer can next place an order. Calling the function to create a copy produces side effects I don't want.

Comment: I haven't tested it actually, but it is mentioned at php.net that this is only aviable for    PHP 5.3    and greater.

Comment: @hugo: Yes, the DateTime class requires PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 131):

Clone the date with the [clone](http://php.net/clone) operator:

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = clone $date1;
$date2->add(new DateInterval('P3Y'));
```

Clones are shallow by default, but deep enough for a DateTime. In your own objects, you can define the `__clone()` magic method to clone the properties (i.e. child objects) that make sense to be cloned when the parent object changes.

(I'm not sure why the documentation thinks a good example of needing to clone an object is GTK. Who uses GTK in PHP?)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how do you know it's deep enough for DateTime? Which attributes remain references and which are copied by value? For example, I can change the time and timezone and it won't affect the clone?

Comment: @David: I know it's deep enough for DateTime because I tried it, and it worked for me. I didn't try changing the timezone or any other things, just the basic time and date.

Comment: Using Xdebug, var_dump($date1) reports that it contains 'date' => string, 'timezone_type' => int & 'timezone' => string. Since it doesn't appear to contain any arrays or objects, just basic scalars, a shallow clone should be fine.

Answer (score 52):

PHP 5.5.0 introduced [DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php). [add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.add.php) and [modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.modify.php) methods of this class return new objects.

```
$date1 = new DateTimeImmutable();
$date2 = $date1->add(new DateInterval('P3Y'));
```

Comment: Note that unfortunately you can't just swap a `DateTime` with a `DateTimeImmutable`. There's at least `IntlDateFormatter::formatObject` that doesn't like immutables (returns `false` instead of the formatted string).

Comment: @user276648 This bug is now fixed in php 7.1.5 http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.1.5

Answer (score 24):

## TLDR (PHP 5.5+ / 7.0.0+ / 8.0.0+):

**Use [`DateTimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php): it does not alter the original instance** :-)

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTimeImmutable(); // Immutable => VERY IMPORTANT
$date2 = $date1->modify('+3years');
// see that $date1 still has the original year
echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // outputs 2022-05-01 12:59:50
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // outputs 2025-05-01 12:59:50
```

BTW: If you use `Carbon` there is also [`CarbonImmutable`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

PHP docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php

## Simple as that :)

### Old answer(rewritten) (don't recommend anymore!):

Shallow copy used to be enough - Deep copy-ing DateTime didn't make sense back then, since we could easily introspect the DateTime instance and see that there were only simple types that are copied by value (there were no *references*).

Following code however stopped working in PHP7.4 (most likely the future solution will be somewhere around Reflection class/object),

```
class TestDateTime extends DateTime{
  public function test(){
   //*this* way also outputs private variables if any...
   var_dump( get_object_vars($this) );    
  }
}
$test = (new TestDateTime())->test();
```

used to output

```
array(3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-08-21 11:38:48.760390"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

so there are no references, just simple types => there was no real reason to *deep* copy, however ***I don't recommend using this anymore in the future.***

Comment: I would like to see the source of clone doing shallow copy. Does it mean it is possible to do deep copy too in PHP? I thought there is just "clone" to copy object but not just reference, which for me sounds like a deep copy?

Comment: @barell not sure if I understand what you're asking, but **`clone`** keyword does **shallow copy** => copies simple values like ints, strings, ..., if there is a reference on another object, it copies only the reference to that object. Deep copy would mean creating a new object for each copied object etc - is it more clear now?

Comment: I didn't know about object references inside cloning object part. Thanks, that is very useful to know. I wish I looked into https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php earlier!

Comment: @barell Yep it is, it is the very difference between shallow and deep copying :) Glad I could help ! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should change your `DateTime` to `DateTimeImmutable`

```
// from date time
$date = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable($mutableDate)
```

then you can call any method on the `DateTime` without worrying about it change

Comment: This is really an answer to a different question.

Comment: @BillyONeal I might have not explained fully how, But this is a solution to this problem as the source of this problem is how calling the method `add` on `date2` changes the value of `date1` and there is no way to copy the value of `DateTime` variable unless you have an `DateTimeImmutable`