# Converting PHP DateTime Object from One Timezone to Another

Tags: php, datetime

I have a PHP DateTime Object where the timezone has already been set to America/New_York.

I'd like to clone this object and and change the timezone of the clone to be UTC.

The resulting time should be the same moment, but the time of day should be adjusted for the new timezone.

Most examples I see suggest converting to and from string formats, which I'm not getting accurate results with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579471/5962802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clone a PHP DateTime object and change the timezone of the clone to UTC, you can utilize the `DateTime::setTimezone` method along with the `DateTime::format` method to create a new DateTime object.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates this:

```php
$originalDateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

// Clone the original DateTime object
$clonedDateTime = clone $originalDateTime;

// Change the timezone of the cloned object to UTC
$clonedDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

// Get the formatted date and time in UTC
$utcDateTimeString = $clonedDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo 'Original DateTime: ' . $originalDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . $originalDateTime->getTimezone()->getName() . "\n";
echo 'Cloned DateTime (UTC): ' . $utcDateTimeString . ' ' . $clonedDateTime->getTimezone()->getName() . "\n";
```

In the above code, we first create the original DateTime object with the timezone set to 'America/New_York'. Then, we clone the original DateTime object using the `clone` keyword to create a new object with the same date and time values. Next, we change the timezone of the cloned object to 'UTC' using the `setTimezone` method. Finally, we retrieve the formatted date and time in the UTC timezone using the `format` method.

The output will display the original DateTime in the 'America/New_York' timezone and the cloned DateTime in the 'UTC' timezone.

Note: It's important to use the `clone` keyword when creating the clone of the DateTime object to ensure that the original object remains unaffected.

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time in PHP, you are better off using [DateTimeImmutable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) objects, which work the same as [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects, but all their methods return a new object, rather than changing the existing one.

With that, there is a method to do exactly what you want: [DateTimeImmutable::setTimezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.settimezone.php). Adapting the example from that manual page (see [live demo](https://3v4l.org/vuLUT)):

```
$newYorkDateTime = new DateTimeImmutable('2023-06-09 09:30', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

$utcDateTime = $newYorkDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo $newYorkDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
echo $utcDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

If you really need to work with mutable `DateTime` objects, you will need to [clone](https://www.php.net/clone) the object first, then modify the clone, to avoid it being modified in place ([live demo](https://3v4l.org/UlFiR)):

```
$newYorkDateTime = new DateTime('2023-06-09 09:30', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

$utcDateTime = clone $newYorkDateTime;
$utcDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo $newYorkDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
echo $utcDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

If you are given a `DateTime` object by some other code, and want to use `DateTimeImmutable` in your own code, you can use [DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfrommutable.php) or (since PHP 8.0) [DateTimeImmutable::createFromInterface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfrominterface.php) (which accepts either `DateTime` or `DateTimeImmutable` objects), like this ([live demo](https://3v4l.org/Y1eHb)):

```
$newYorkDateTime = new DateTime('2023-06-09 09:30', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$newYorkDateTimeImmutable = DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable($newYorkDateTime);

$utcDateTime = $newYorkDateTimeImmutable->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo $newYorkDateTimeImmutable->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
echo $utcDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```